# Skip symbol when load data from flat file using Informatica 9.5.1

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I nead create new workflows for load flat file to Oracle DB.

I have flat file with ~ 70 columns and one of this columns include symbol  which I want skip because when load line whis this symbols I don't get result what I want get.

[image: the symbol]

[image: When I upload a file, I get an offset of two columns.I don't need these offsets.]

When I put spaces in place of characters , there is no problem with loading and everything is put in its place.

How can I skip them so that the data does not go to the number of such characters in the line?

Answer (score 1):

Please use informatica regular expressions -
`REG_REPLACE(COL_NAME,'[^a-z0-9A-Z;,~!@#$%&*()_-+]','')`  - This will remove everything but all of the stuff with your symbol.
Alternately you can use
`REPLACECHR(1,COL_NAME,CHR(xx),'')` - where xx is the ASCII value(int) of your symbol. You can easily find this value in internet.